# Cocoapods 1.0: "xcodeproj was renamed to `project`. Please use that from now on."

Tags: cocoapods

I do get the warning `xcodeproj was renamed to`project`. Please use that from now on.` when running `pod install` with Cocoapods 1.0.

Also, `[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"org.cocoapods.xyz"]` returns `nil`.

With version 0.39.0 I don't get the warning and `[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"org.cocoapods.xyz"]` returns a valid bundle.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Looks to your Podfile. You have string like

`xcodeproj 'MyProj/MyProj.xcodeproj'`

just replace **xcodeproj** to **project**

`project 'MyProj/MyProj.xcodeproj'`

Answer (score 0):

2020. Just stumbled upon this question. After renaming the `xcodeproj` to `project`, the warning was still there. I realized that the string xcodeproj path wasn't the one that needs to be renamed to `project`, but instead it's the param/key of Cocoapod `xcodeproj`.

This happens if you want to explicitly indicate the targeted project file. In my case, I had to explicitly indicate it, since my goal is to have a single Podfile that targets two different projects.

---

So from this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs'

platform :ios, '13.0'

def commonpods
  pod 'Mixpanel'
end

workspace 'MixpanelSample'
xcodeproj 'MixpanelSample_Swift/MixpanelSample_Swift.xcodeproj'
xcodeproj 'MixpanelSample_Objc/MixpanelSample_Objc.xcodeproj'

target 'MixpanelSample_Swift' do
    xcodeproj 'MixpanelSample_Swift/MixpanelSample_Swift.xcodeproj'
    commonpods
end

target 'MixpanelSample_Objc' do
    xcodeproj 'MixpanelSample_Objc/MixpanelSample_Objc.xcodeproj'
    commonpods
end
```

---

to this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs'

platform :ios, '13.0'

def commonpods
  pod 'Mixpanel'
end

workspace 'MixpanelSample'
project 'MixpanelSample_Swift/MixpanelSample_Swift.xcodeproj'
project 'MixpanelSample_Objc/MixpanelSample_Objc.xcodeproj'

target 'MixpanelSample_Swift' do
    project 'MixpanelSample_Swift/MixpanelSample_Swift.xcodeproj'
    commonpods
end

target 'MixpanelSample_Objc' do
    project 'MixpanelSample_Objc/MixpanelSample_Objc.xcodeproj'
    commonpods
end
```

Answer (score -1):

[Release Notes](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.0.0.beta.5) 1.0.0.beta.3 (2016-02-03). [GitHub issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Core/issues/298)

> Rename the `xcodeproj` Podfile directive to `project`.

Just replace `xcodeproj` by `project`